# Estoy haciendo las rutas protegidas enviando el token por las cookies es una app web MERN

Tags: nodejs, express, jsonwebtoken

Se crea el token con el registro y el login se guarda en las cookies pero cuando hice una ruta protegida, elimina el token no lo envia a las demas rutas falta que envie la cookies a las demas rutas.

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken"; 
import { JWT_SECRET } from "../config.js"; 


      export const authRequired = (req, res, next) => { 
       try {
            const { token } = req.cookies; 

             if (!token) {
            return res.status(401).json({ message: "No hay token, autorización denegada" }); 
             }

            jwt.verify(token, JWT_SECRET, (error, user) => { 
                if (error) {
                 return res.status(403).json({ message: "Token inválido" }); 
             }
            // Establecer la cookie en la respuesta
              //res.cookie('token', token);
             req.user = user;
              console.log(user);
              next(); 
             });
          } catch (error) {
           console.error("Error al verificar el token:", error);
          return res.status(500).json({ message: "Error interno del servidor" });
          }
          };
```

controller.js

```
     export const pedidos = (req, res) => {
       res.send('pedidos')
        }
```

router.js

```
         router.get("/pedidos", authRequired, pedidos);
```